# React-Native cant find main project file on build

Tags: javascript, objective-c, npm, react-native, cocoapods

Recently implemented cocoapods into a React Native project. Now RN is throw this error after a successful build....

[image]

No errors in Xcode during build time... but Xcode gives me these warnings

[image]

Corresponding `RCTUIManager.m`: https://pastebin.com/F7shCt8M

Xcode log:

```
2017-04-07 14:06:59.714 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:72] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x6000001a5400> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6080000c50f0>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2017-04-07 14:07:00.409 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Native module cannot be null.
2017-04-07 14:07:00.414 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.
2017-04-07 14:07:00.430 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Requiring module "215", which threw an exception.
2017-04-07 14:07:00.435 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Native module cannot be null.
2017-04-07 14:07:00.436 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new XMLHttpRequest()')
2017-04-07 14:07:00.441 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring module "215", which threw an exception.
2017-04-07 14:07:00.533 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:275] Running application zelosApp ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2017-04-07 14:07:00.535 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2017-04-07 14:07:00.538 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new XMLHttpRequest()')
2017-04-07 14:07:00.539 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

`Podfile`: https://pastebin.com/CAqehNMZ

`index.ios.js`: https://pastebin.com/j5nbaRaf

[image]

Not sure what the problem is here... Any ideas?

Comment: The warnings for the `React` project are likely not related as they're internal to the React code. Can you post your `index.ios.js`? Which modules are you loading there? Have you implemented a native module?

Comment: I implemented react and native modules in my Podfile. Could that affect header search paths or conflicts? I'm unfamiliar with cocoapods but using it for a react-native-maps dependency: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Comment: Podfile says you're using `react-native-maps` but screenshot of linked libraries doesn't show it. Have you run `react-native link`?

Comment: Yes, but I get a linker error of `ld: library not found for -lAirMaps
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: You have to link your native libs. Seems like the most recent version of `react-native-maps` has a broken `xcodeproj` file. Try following the instructions at https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1193 (I found it through https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1201).

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments: the `React`-related warnings are unrelated as they're about `React` rather than your project.

The error likely indicates that you have not linked a native library to your project. This should be done using `react-native link`.

There's a known issue with the latest `react-native-maps` component (v0.14) that breaks compilation following a `react-native link`. See https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1193 for the solution:

```
open AirMaps project inside Libraries folder
remove reference of RCTConvert+MapKit.h/m
add reference to RCTConvert+AirMap.h/m (from node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps)
```